# System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe") returns false

Tags: .net, windows-7, 64-bit

So I am working on a simple .NET program for work and hit a bit of a weird roadblock I can't figure out.  The application makes use of a configuration file which adds applications to a dropdown menu.  However, before it's added to the menu, it does a system.io.file.exists to verify that the file exists, at least at the time the menu is created.

However, System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe") returns false, but the executable is there.  Likewise, stikynot.exe also returns false.  Other files in the system32 directory return true(like notepad).  I can filestat these applications, but my .net program just can't read them them and system.io.file.exists returns false.  I have checked various permissions with no luck.  It seems to be isolated to a few applications, but I am not sure why.

Comment: Does the account that the program is running under have permissions to browse to that location? If not, you will get false on this call.

Comment: Yes, and it can find other applications in that directory just fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# Check if an executable exists in the windows path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855956/c-sharp-check-if-an-executable-exists-in-the-windows-path)

Comment: Project + Properties, Compile tab, change Platform target to AnyCPU.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a feature of 64 bit Windows.

In x64 you have two folders with system files: **system32** and **SysWOW64**.

If you put anything in **system32**, it will be seen by all **64 bit** applications. **SysWOW64** is there for compatibility reasons - anything put there will be visible by **32 bit** (sic!) apps.

So as far as .NET is concerned, the file does not exist. It works for notepad, because notepad.exe is present in both of those directories.

You can test this behaviour. Create a text file in one of the directories, but not the other and check for its existence. Then change your project configuration (right click on solution -> Configuration Manager) between x86 and x64 and enjoy the result.

Comment: I cannot believe this issue that was haunting me all day. Thanks SO

Answer (score 3):

I have a crazy bug relate to this topic. Thank ya23.

In my case, just changing project Properties > Build > uncheck Prefer 32-bit