# System.IO.File.Exists() different answer from x86 and x64 applications

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with Update 3 installed.  I am using C# targeting .NET framework 4.5.

I have a method that starts like this:

```
public void Open(System.String filePath)
{
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(. . .);

    . . .
}
```

The value of the `filePath` parameter is this:

`"C:\\Users\\Jonathan.DeCarlo\\Source\\Repos\\PoliticalClassifier\\src\\PoliticalClassifier.DataSource.Tests\\TestFiles\\Social_Economic_DataMicro.xlsx"`

That path does indeed exist on my machine.  This application is compiled as "Any CPU."   I am running it on a machine with Windows 7 x64 installed.  If I let the applicatoin run as an x64 process, the `FileNotFoundException` is thrown even though the file does exist.  If I force the application to run as an x86 process, then the the exception is NOT thrown (which should be the case).

Why does `System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)` return a different result when the application is running as an x64 process as opposed to an x86 process?

Comment: Can you confirm that the filePath string is the same for both x86 and x64? Is the filePath being set by environment variables of any kind?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a new console application that simply calls `File.Exists` with that same `filePath`?

Comment: @ClosedEyesSeeing - I have confirmed that the filePath is the same in both.  Also, there is no environment variables being used to figure the path out.  I've changed it to a hard-coded path for testing purposes.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it see a file outside of the user profile? Like C:\Test.txt?

Comment: Possibly because .Net doesn't have full 64bit support yet, I could be completely wrong though.

Comment: @Pharap: "Possibly because .Net doesn't have full 64bit support yet" _Really?_ I haven't heard of this before (EDIT: especially for as something as fundamental as `File.Exists`). But then again, I haven't heard explicitly of support either... :-S

Comment: @ChrisSinclair .Net runs on a stack-based VM, and I remember reading that every item on the stack is a 32-bit value, so it's possible that could be related. I might be wrong of course, it's just the first thing that came to mind regarding things that could cause a difference between x32 and x64 proccesses

Comment: Sounds like a [sysWOW64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993733/system-io-file-existsc-windows-system32-snippingtool-exe-returns-false) problem, however for the user folder their really shouldn't be a problem-

Comment: @Pharap: Ahh sorry I misunderstood. I thought you meant that compiling .NET for x64 _isn't supported_, not that all operations that execute in x64 that _could_ be 64bit operations are actually implemented as such.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Win7 x64.

Comment: @JonathanDeCarlo Why not try the Traditional Try..Catch rather than throwing exception yourself? I tried to reproduce on my machine and making sure file path and name is correct and it does not reproduce an error for both x64 and x86. I have also by the way Windows 7 64bit on my machine and am using VS2012 targeting .Net Framework 4.5 as well.

Comment: Try inspecting the WinAPI calls via ProcMon to see what is getting passed to GetFileAttributes (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

Comment: ProcMon could help as Mitch suggests.

How exactly are you launching it as 32 bit and 64 bit explicitly? It could well be a file permission problem; make sure you run it elevated as an Administrator in both cases.

Comment: do you have the same problem with any other files in other paths?

Comment: if you get the folder path using: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)); is the file found?

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for all of the comments.  I tried a number of them and found that I could not reproduce the problem for any file other than the one I pointed to with my original code.  Over the last couple days, I began to see my hard drive fail on me.  After getting a new hard drive, setting it all up again, and running the aforementioned program, I no longer see this issue.  I can't be 100% sure about this, but I'm going to assume that the file I was trying to open was corrupted by a failing hard drive.  I apologize for the wild goose chase.