# SQL2012 LocalDB: how to check in c#  if it is currently installed?

Tags: sql-server-2012, localdb

How to check in c# code if LocalDB currently installed? also, how to check if SQLNCLI11 presents in system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [nuget](https://github.com/martincostello/sqllocaldb) package that wraps up working with SQLLocalDB
Has the following command

```
SqlLocalDbApi.IsLocalDBInstalled()
```

Answer (score 16):

Check if LocalDB is installed, by looking for this registry key:

```
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions\11.0]
```

SQLNCLI11 - check the file version and presence of this file: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\sqlncli.dll`

Comment: I have a little confusion. Need to know a little something to clear. In MS Visual Studio 2010, I can create database and work with it. (probably MS SQL Server express, which is by default integrated with VS 2010). Is it what we're refering as LocalDB?

Comment: No, not exactly the same, but similar products

Comment: This won't work if the user uninstalls localdb. The key is not removed.

Comment: You might try HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11E.LOCALDB\Setup

Answer (score 3):

Here is a VB.NET example checking for LOCALDB

```
Public Shared Function CheckLocalDBExists() As Boolean
    Dim s As String = ""
    Dim reg As RegistryKey
    Dim rtn As Boolean = False
    reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions\12.0", True)
    Try
        s = reg.GetValue("ParentInstance", "").ToString
        reg.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        s = Nothing
    End Try
    'MessageBox.Show(s)
    If s = "MSSQL12E.LOCALDB" Then
        rtn = True
    End If
    Return rtn
End Function
```

Comment: Note: This test is for localdb 2014.   For 2012 you need to check for installed version 11.0 and MSSQL11E.LOCALDB. (sorry for any confusion)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855956/check-if-an-executable-exists-in-the-windows-path)
to check for the existence of `sqllocaldb.exe`

Like so:

```
public static bool IsLocalDBInstalled()
{
    return ExistsOnPath("SqlLocalDB.exe"); ;
}

public static bool ExistsOnPath(string fileName)
{
    return GetFullPath(fileName) != null;
}

public static string GetFullPath(string fileName)
{
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
        return Path.GetFullPath(fileName);

    var values = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
    foreach (var path in values.Split(';'))
    {
        var fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
        if (File.Exists(fullPath))
            return fullPath;
    }
    return null;
}
```