# Discover all sql server instances including localdb

Tags: c#, sql-server

I would like to get an `enum` in c# which contains all sql server instances including `localdb`, at this time I have tried looking in:

```
- System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer()
```

both not yielding the localdb instance. However ms server management studio seems to be able to discover it, usualy in (LocalDb)\v11.0

[image: Server names in SQLServer management]
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suspect for localdb, SSMS is using this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628316/sql2012-localdb-how-to-check-in-c-sharp-if-it-is-currently-installed

Comment: seems kinda vague to be using the existance of a registery key to check the existance. I'm sure the management studio doesn't search for a key to display this enum. But thanks for your reply!