# MVC Tutorial, Server name not found or cannot be accessed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im pretty new to MVC so I tried myself at this tutorial which seemed a good idea: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Everything went really well until the point when I got to chapter 5 to create a Model.
I created the model in "almost" the same way as the tutorial says (Didnt have the same application context in the dropdown, so I took the one that was presented) and that did work. But when I try to start up the application now I get the following error:

```
A network-related or instance- specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server . The server was not found or it can not be accessed. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server allows remote connections. (provider : SQL Network Interfaces , error : 56 - \ " SQLUserInstance.dll \ " can not be loaded from the location specified in the registry Verify that the function Local Database Runtime SQL Server Express is installed correctly. .
```

The Inner exception would be: % 1 is not a valid Win32 application

Hope someone can help me with this, since I have no clue what Ive done wrong.

Comment: Did you check to make sure that you have the LocalDB functionality installed?

Comment: Did you use a database or not?

Comment: @svanelten how do I check that?

Comment: There is a registry key for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628316/sql2012-localdb-how-to-check-in-c-sharp-if-it-is-currently-installed

Comment: @clement the tutorial says that the database will be created with LocalDB which is installed together Visual Studio.

Comment: @VIP - Did you get the chance to look into my answer? Still you are facing the issue?

Comment: @RahulSingh yeah seems that was the problem I was facing after I found I had to reinstall my VS since there seemed to be some other problem that the LocalDB could not be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably because you have not disconnected the connection, Try this:-

Open Server Explorer -> DBContext (Probably MovieDBContext in your case) , right click on that and select `Close Connection`.

Also, you need to set the right connection string name for the entity framework database context. Check in `Web.Config` file, your ConnectionStrings key name should exactly match with your DBContext (MoviesDBContext here).

Also, I noticed you said, you couldn't find the right DBContext in dropdown that's because you might not have build your solution before doing that.